# How can I change the layout of a page (plain TeX)?

Tags: plain-tex

I need to change both horizontal and vertical dimensions of the output pages.  Is there a simple way to do it in plain TeX?

Comment: Change `\hsize` and `\vsize`. For placing the text block on the page, the simplest method is acting on `\hoffset` and `\voffset`; the *correct* method would be modifying the output routing.

Comment: @egreg  But it works with the ``.dvi`` file and not with the ``.pdf``.  (Both if I use ``dvipdf`` or directly ``pdftex``).  For example, if I write ``\divide\vsize by 2``, then the pages are shrinked only in the ``.dvi``: in the ``.pdf`` the pages remain the same, except that the bottom margin increases.

Comment: The `dvi` file has no notion of the physical output page. Please, be more specific about your workflow. Why are you using `dvipdf` and not `pdftex` directly?

Comment: Because there are some plain tex macros on which pdftex works differently than tex.  But, even if I directly use ``pdftex``, the shape of the pages doesn't change.  Instead, by compiling with ``tex``, if I open the ``.dvi`` file with a viewer (I use evince), then it appears right.   The file I am compiling is
``\divide\vsize by 2
Hello world!
\bye``

Comment: "There are some Plain TeX macros on which `pdftex` works differently from `tex`”: really? Can you give an example? However, as I said, a DVI file has no notion whatsoever of the physical page, so probably Evince uses some default space around the text block. Can you be more specific about your needs? It seems changing also the PDF output pate, but it's not in your question.

Comment: @egreg For example ``epsf``.  If I compile with tex and then I use ``dvipdf``, then the images gets positioned right;  instead, if I use ``pdftex`` directly, the images get positioned wrong in the pages.  Maybe my question is not properly formulated.  I meant: How can I change the dimension of the page, so that when I open it with Evince it appears right?  For example, how can I have A4 sized pages rotated so that the horizontal dimension is greater than the vertical one?

Comment: You can probably use `\pdfpagewidth=<dimen>`/`\pdfpageheight=<dimen>` with pdfTeX/XeTeX at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `opmac.tex` which defines `\margins` macro for setting page dimensions and margins comfortable. The following example sets all four margins to 1in, but the page format is changed.

```
\input opmac

\margins/1 a5 (1,1,1,1)in  % A5 portrait
% or: \margins/1 a5l (1,1,1,1)in  % A5 landscape
% or: \margins/1 a3 (1,1,1,1)in   % A3 portrait
% etc.
% or: \sdef{pgs:spec}{(200,200)mm}  
% \margins/1 spec (1,1,1,1)in     % special format 200x200 mm 

hello world.

\bye
```

See the `opmac-u-en.pdf` documentation if you need more features.

Note that if the DVI mode is active then page media dimensions isn't set by this macro `\margins`, because it is impossible (DVI doesn't store such information). I don't understand where your evince reads this information when it displays DVI. My evince isn't able display DVI so I can't try.

Comment: Thank's!  I didn't know about ``opmac``, but it seems good.  I actually use ``eplain`` which does similar things.
My evince displays dvi just like it displays pdf :)  I don't know why yours can't do it